# Trabalhando com Rotas no Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Essa é a estrutura do meu projeto onde fica minha pagina;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é meu controller;

```
  public function create()
    {
        return view(imoveis.create);
    }
```

Está configurado assim minha rota, está no meu arquivo `web.php`;

```
Route::resource('imoveis', 'ImovelController');
```

E está me retornado essa mensagem de erro na URL:  `http://localhost:8000/imoveis/create`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde será que errei?

Comment: A mensagem de erro explica o problema, como constante não definida, ou seja, imoveis.create não existe deve ter uma apas simples ou dupla acredito que resolva tipo `view("imoveis.create");`

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, você está certo, é falta das *Aspas*.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic pode postar a resposta, pois você está certo, funcionou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mensagem de erro explica o significado do erro, [dizendo que essa constante não existe](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.constants.php), o que se espera no seu código é entre aspas, exemplo:

```
public function create()
{
   return view('imoveis.create');
}
```

Comment: Valeu pela diga, é porque ainda estou começando  :)